# Locating definition of a tactic in Coq proofs

Tags: coq

In studying Coq proofs of other authors, I often encounter a tactic, lets say "inv eq Heq" or "intro_b". I want to understand such tactics.

How can I find if it is a Coq tactic or a Tactic Notation defined somewhere in my current project?

Second, is there a way to find its definition?

I used SearchAbout, Search, Locate and Print but could not find answers to the above questions.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to use

```
Print Ltac <tacticname>.
```

to print the code of a user-defined tactic (according to the [documentation](http://coq.inria.fr/distrib/V8.4/refman/Reference-Manual012.html#@command252)).

---

To find where it is defined... I guess you're going to need grep unfortunately, `Locate` does not work for tactics names it seems.

Comment: `Locate Ltac` is the tactic version of `Locate`

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned before, `Print Ltac ...` prints the code of a user-defined tactic.

To locate a user-defined tactic (i.e. to know where its defined), use `Locate Ltac ...`. It gives you the fully qualified name. Then use `Locate Library` to find the corresponding file.

Comment: @SpaceBeers: I think you're just confused. This is an answer, not a critique or request for clarification in any way.

Comment: Yes totally. Hit the wrong button. Comment removed.

Comment: Which version of Coq is this for?  Coq gives me a syntax error on `Locate Tactic`, but `Locate Ltac` works fine